# How to check whether form data is changed or not, excluding few fields on form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check whether any field is changed or not excluding few field on form.For this I tried following one.

```
$('#FormId').not('#elementId').data("changed")
```

But it is not excluding the element with id 'elementId'.

Comment: Of course an element that has the id `FormId` does not have the id `elementId` at the same time. `$('#FormId').not('#elementId')` is the same, as simply `$('#FormId')` would be.

Comment: There is a form with id "FormId" and it has element with "elementID" and few more elements.And i want to check whether any other element is changed on from rather than specified "elementId".

Comment: I get that. I was just explaining to you why your attempt can’t work. It looks like you are not aware what .not really does, so you should go read up on it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
// this binds the following function on any inputs type=text under #FormId
$('#FormId input[type=text]')bind("change", function(){
    // do something
});

// You can add more elements, or classes by adding commas to the selector
$('#FormId input[type=text], .anotherclass, .onemoreclass')bind("change", function(){
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to check whether form data change it or not
here is one approach i have use.

1. Create one Variable like: oldForm save in ready with old value
2. Create on change event for all input any change it will trigger
   below is code suggestion for same

   ```
   var oldFormData = '';

   $(function () {
   oldFormData == $('#FormId').serialize();

      $('form :input').on('change input', function () {
       var isChange = $('#FormId').serialize() !== origForm
      });
   })
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [quick and dirty example](https://codepen.io/teoulas/pen/KgWprx).

Let's say you want to mark the inputs that you want to track with a data attribute (`data-change-tracking` in this example).

**HTML**

```
<form action="/echo/html/" method="post">
  <p>
    <label>A text input</label>
    <input data-change-tracking="true" value="abc"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>A select</label>
    <select data-change-tracking="true">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>      
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>A textarea</label>
    <textarea data-change-tracking="true">old</textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Not tracked</label>
    <input value="123" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Then, let's just add a `dirty` class when the input has changed from the previous value:

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
  $('[data-change-tracking]').each(function(){
    $(this).data('previousValue', this.value);
  });
  $('form').on('change', '[data-change-tracking]', function(ev) {
    if (ev.target.value !== $(ev.target).data('previousValue')) {
      $(ev.target).addClass('dirty');
    } else {
      $(ev.target).removeClass('dirty');
    }
  });
});
```